# How do I move the cursor 2 lines up to the beginning?

Tags: python, shell

How do I move the cursor 2 lines up to the beginning?

I have an application that outputs some data to the console, after which it turns on a timer to update the data. The whole output looks like this

```
Important data 1
Important data 2
Important data 3
Next update data after 01 minutes 51 seconds ...
To stop the program, press Ctrel+E
```

But there is a problem when the timer size becomes smaller, the line is not completely erased

> Next update data after 55 seconds ...seconds ...

And it should be

> Next update data after 55 seconds ...

I know why this is happening, and I had an idea to avoid such an effect, I'll just fill it with spaces before outputting a line.
I want to output empty lines to erase the old data and output an updated timer

```
clear_line_timer = ''.join(" " for i in range(len_line_timer))
clear_line_info = ''.join(" " for i in range(len_line_info))
line_timer = 'Next update data after ' + timerToString(seconds) + ' ...'
line_info = 'To stop the program, press Ctrl+E'
len_line_timer = len(line_timer)
len_line_info = len(line_info)
```

In theory, this should work, **but I do not know how to return the cursor pointer to the beginning of the line with a timer.
How can I return the cursor to the beginning of the timer line before output?**
I want it to work like in Windows and Linux/Unix

*Full code for playback*

```
import time

len_line_timer = 0
len_line_info = 0


def timerToString(seconds: int) -> str:
    if seconds is not None:
        seconds = int(seconds)
        d = seconds // (3600 * 24)
        h = seconds // 3600 % 24
        m = seconds % 3600 // 60
        s = seconds % 3600 % 60
        if d > 0:
            return '{:02d}d {:02d}h {:02d}m {:02d}s'.format(d, h, m, s)
        elif h > 0:
            return '{:02d}h {:02d}m {:02d}s'.format(h, m, s)
        elif m > 0:
            return '{:02d} minutes {:02d} seconds'.format(m, s)
        elif s > 0:
            return '{:02d} seconds'.format(s)
    return 'now'


def timer(seconds):
    global len_line_timer
    global len_line_info

    clear_line_timer = ''.join(" " for i in range(len_line_timer))
    clear_line_info = ''.join(" " for i in range(len_line_info))
    line_timer = 'Next update data after ' + timerToString(seconds) + ' ...'
    line_info = 'To stop the program, press Ctrl+E'
    len_line_timer = len(line_timer)
    len_line_info = len(line_info)
    ####################################################################################
    # You need to somehow return the cursor pointer to the beginning of the timer line #
    ####################################################################################
    print(clear_line_timer + '\r', end='')
    print(line_timer + '\r', end='')
    print(clear_line_info + '\r', end='')
    print(line_info + '\r', end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Important data 1")
    print("Important data 2")
    back_timer = 70
    counter = back_timer
    while True:

        timer(counter)

        counter -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if counter <= 0:
            counter = back_timer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this isn't really a `python` question, more of a Linux shell question (or Windows, if that's what you're using).

For bash-compatible shells, there are control codes to move the cursor around: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html. Just `print()` these codes to STDOUT from python as normal.

You can also check out https://pypi.org/project/ansi-escapes/ which does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this bash function for text positioning in terminal:

```
# Text positioning, usage: XY 10 10 'Hello World!'
XY () { printf "\e[$2;${1}H$3"; }
```